Showing or hiding multiple symbols at once in QGIS
In the layer panel of QGIS 3.34, it is possible to select multiple layers using either mouse drag or shift + arrow up/down and then pressing the space bar to show/hide them all at once.
However, doing the exact same thing for the symbols only shows/hides the last selected symbol.

Is there a way to show/hide multiple selected symbols simultaneously in QGIS, as we can for layers?

I don't know of any simple way to do that. Maybe a feature request?
